# How to set listview button text according to the position?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button

I have a `listview` with 20 items. In every row of the listview, there is a `Button`. I want to change the Button text according to the position.

1. If the position is 2 & 3, button text will be "Invited".
2. If the position is 5 and 8, button text will be "Sent".
3. For all other position, button text should be "Invite".

The weird issue is when I scroll,texts got exchanged.

Following what I have tried so far,

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public MyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        Button text=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Log.i("POSITION:", ""+position);
        if(position==2 || position==3)
        text.setText("Invited");
        if(position==5 || position==8)
        {
            text.setText("Sent");
        }

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your issue?

Comment: The issue is when I scroll, the texts are assigned to some other buttons present in the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the logic to this:

```
if (position==2 || position==3) {
    text.setText("Invited");
} 
else if (position==5 || position==8) {
    text.setText("Sent");
}
else {
    text.setText("Invite");
}
```

Because of view recycling, without the fallback "else" you will get the wrong text in the wrong rows.

Comment: Well in this case, except position 5 & 8, other buttons will be assigned with a "Invite" text.

Comment: 2 and 3 will get "Invited", 5 and 8 will get "Sent", the rest will get "Invite". This is what you asked for right?

Comment: Yeah.I was really silly to ask this question.Actually this requirement is part of a big and complex project  and to make it simple I asked this question.Anyway your answer is acceptable for this question.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could you please tell me why your answer is not working when i add a extra line to the else if condition. I added "text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);"

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
 else
    {
        text.setText("Invite");
    }
```

after

```
if(position==5 || position==8)
```

Comment: I need 3 different texts in the buttons.Your solution will only work for 2 texts.

Comment: May be it happened as In your code..u forgot to put { } within your first if Condition..if(position==2 || position==3)
text.setText("Invited");

Answer (score 0):

```
 public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
        //check above function return the view and now call the function  

               View v = getViewByPosition(position, list);
                LinearLayout vwParentRow1 = (LinearLayout) v;
                TextView btnChild1 = (TextView) vwParentRow1.getChildAt(0);
                String firstcolumn = btnChild1.getText().toString();
```

//firstcolumn variable store the value of first column according to postion of list view

Comment: Consider adding some explanation